# I didn't get error when try to connect SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, azure, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Virtual Machine in Windows Azure with SQL Server 2016. This VM has a firewall with Azure, where I allow the IP to connect to the server. And also my project is an ASP.NET Web API 2 with ADO.NET for Data Access Layer.

The thing is all set; everything is working fine (Good!). But If I try to connect from another place with an IP that is not added to the firewall rules, I don't get any error, only still to try to execute the command. Normally if I use the SQL Managment I get an error.

This is my parameter in my connection string

```
Server=vm.XXXXXX.azure.com;Database={database};User ID={userid};Password={password};Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;Connection Timeout=300;ConnectRetryCount=4;ConnectRetryInterval=1
```

So, this is extract code that I executed:

```
using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(myCString))
{
    using (SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand())
    {
        string queryString;
        queryString = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE (ID = @ID) ";
        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(Utilities.GetSQLParameter("ID", 1234, SqlDbType.VarChar));

        dbCommand.CommandText = queryString;
        dbCommand.Connection = dbConnection;

        dbConnection.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader dr = dbCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                Value = dr[Field].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                Value = "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In summary, I want to get the error if I cannot find the VM because the firewall is blocking the access.

Comment: When you said "try to connect from another place", did you mean you request to web api URL like `http://www.example.com/api/someFunction` from browser or REST client? If so, api code executed on the server itself so there is no blocking but when you tried SSMS it directly connect to SQL server from the caller machine and hence gets blocked by firewall.

Answer (score 0):

The connection failure occurs at `dbConnection.Open`.
Wrap your code in  a`try/catch` block and treat the error *if* it occurs.

A list of available *catchable* exceptions can be found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open(v=vs.110).aspx

```
try
{
    dbConnection.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader dr = dbCommand.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            Value = dr[Field].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            Value = "";
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //Do some treatment
}
finally
{
    //If connection has been opened, close it.
    if(dbConnection.ConnectionState == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        dbConnection.Close();  
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you use USING clear all your "managed resources"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStringName"].ToString()))
using (SqlCommand mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand())
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        mySqlCommand.Connection = conn;
        mySqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        mySqlCommand.CommandText = "getCities";
        mySqlCommand.CommandTimeout = Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionTimeout"].ToString());

        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@param", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = param;     
        da.SelectCommand = mySqlCommand;
        da.Fill(ds, "cities");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {            
      // LOG HERE the errors    
    }
} // end using
```